# How can a water-resistant device can not have a dust resistance to it?

Tags: electronics

I have read about [IP Ratings](https://www.dsmt.com/resources/ip-rating-chart/) on how it rates on the resistance of the device to either dust or water.

But I've seen some devices that have an IPX7/IPX8 resistance (one example would be the [Fold 3](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_z_fold3_5g-10906.php)). This would mean the the device has no dust resistance rating to it.

My questions are:

1. How can a water resistant device with all the seals in it, not have a dust resistance?
2. Isn't dust larger than water, therefore shouldn't the dust particles be also blocked by the seals meant for water?

Comment: Dust may have other effects than getting into the device: e.g. blocking transparent windows, where water might not be as much of a problem.

Comment: I see, I didn't think of that. 
But I was asking about dust/water ingression, as that's what the IP ratings state.

Comment: My guess is that they just didn't bother testing for dust ingress.

Comment: @DKNguyen, if that would be the case for that device I mentioned above, then alright.  But are there cases where an item (not necessarily a device) is resistant to water ingression but not to dust ingression?

Comment: @RinMinase None come to mind except sand blasting (am I being facetious? who knows?)  Stretching things, there could be a case where the device is resistant to water getting in since it could evaporate or flow out while dust just settles and messes up heatsinks. But that's stretching it since it would be like a vented metal box to protect dust from settling on a heatsink enclosing enclosing another metal box with a heatsink sticking outside of it which in turn protects dust sensitive electronics inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://habr.com/ru/company/pocketbook/blog/407047/) (in Russian) suggests a major difference between IP57 and IPX8 (beside the 7 vs 8):

The X means the device electronics is treated (with conformal coating) to protect the electronics from water but the device itself is not sealed.

This means that, if water (presumably not too clean) gets into the device, algae and other undesired organisms may begin spreading there.

Comment: This seems to be the case, as searching deeper in to the device I mentioned in the question, a part of it was not sealed but treated only with conformal coating.